# Display GUID in MVC 5 View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So I am following the example at http://holsson.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-online-integration-getting-started-late-bound/ to try and create an MVC 5 site that uses CRM as the backing data.  I created a CRMAccount Controller (Could't make one called Account as it was used by the Identity system).

I am able to successfully query the CRM System but when i try to use the Razor Code below in my view, I get the name, but nothing under the accountid is displayed.  The item returned by accountid is a GUID, If I try to set it to a string, the DisplayFor complains that it can't render that.

```
@model IEnumerable<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item["accountid"])
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item["name"])
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

I am only doing this right now for Proof Of Concept.  Eventually, I want to put the two together as a drop down box, but if I can't get the GUID to pull correctly, I'm going to have problems.

EDIT:-------------------------------------------------------------------

I was asked to post the controller code, though something similar was in the example i linked to above.

Here's the code used in my controller.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;

namespace ExternalEntities.Controllers
{
    public class CRMAccountController : Controller
    {
        // GET: CRMAccount
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var service = Session["ServiceProxy"] as IOrganizationService;
            if (service != null)
            {
                var context = new OrganizationServiceContext(service);
                IQueryable<Entity> query = from e in context.CreateQuery("account") select e;
                List<Entity> accts = query.ToList();
                return View(accts);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code for the ViewModel?

Comment: There is no ViewModel in this solution.  I am getting an IEnumerable from directly from the CRM system and passing it as the model to the view.

Comment: Do you see the GUID on the property accountid on the accts list while debuggin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.accountid)
```

instead of

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item["accountid"])
```

for intellisense, also can you show the controller please.

**Edited after some comments back and forth:**

Maybe you have a `DisplayTemplate` that is on your way? Try to do `@item["accountid"]` and see if it still blank. (not using `DisplayFor`)

Comment: The response from the CRM server is not strongly typed.  Accountid is not a property but a key in the Attributes collection.  For brevity I assumed the link to the reference i used would do for the controller, but I will add it here for now.

Comment: If it's a key in the Attributes, could you not try `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Attributes["accountid"])`

Comment: I did.  Still outputting a blank.

Comment: Maybe you have a DisplayTemplate that is on your way? Try to do @item["accountid"] and see if it still blank. (not using DisplayFor)

Comment: It must have been the display template.  The suggestion above, doing the @item["accountid"] worked. If you make it an "answer" I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: @SpaceCowboy74 glad to help, answer edited with suggestion as requested.